# Why is my footer on top of the page and is my html structure arranged correctly?

Tags: css, html

My social network , faq and where to buy's link is arrange inside footer section but it cannot stick it at bottom of my page , and i feel my HTML structure very weird can anyone help me on this ? Thank you
I want it to be like this with the FAQ and Where to Buy at the left bottom , social network logo at right bottom of the page and LOGO in the middle of 4 navigation link[Output that i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsqmU.png)

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

/* Set the width of the side navigation to 0 */
function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url(Images/Clean-Gray-BackGround-620x465.jpg);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  margin: 0;
}

#page {
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 1200px;
}

header {
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px 0 0;
}

.mainnav {
  padding-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
  width: 1200px;
}

button {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Bungee';
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 16px 16px 40px 0px;
}

.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.divider {
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 260px;
}

.divider2 {
  margin-left: 150px;
}

#submenu {
  display: none;
  background-color: transparen;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 60px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}

#submenu a {
  color: black;
  padding: 0 0 40 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover #submenu {
  display: block;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 45%;
  margin: -48px 0 0 -98px;
}

#cart a {
  position: absolute;
  /* Position them relative to the browser window */
  right: -80px;
  /* Position them outside of the screen */
  transition: 0.3s;
  /* Add transition on hover */
  padding: 15px;
  /* 15px padding */
  width: 100px;
  /* Set a specific width */
  text-decoration: none;
  /* Remove underline */
  font-size: 20px;
  /* Increase font size */
  color: black;
  /* White text color */
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 15px 0px 0px 15px;
}

#cart a:hover {
  right: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  /* 100% Full-height */
  width: 0;
  /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Stay on top */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  /* Black*/
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /* Disable horizontal scroll */
  padding-top: 60px;
  /* Place content 60px from the top */
  transition: 0.5s;
  /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidenav */
}


/* The navigation menu links */

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s
}


/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */

.sidenav a:hover,
.offcanvas a:focus {
  color: blanchedalmond;
}


/* Position and style the close button (top right corner) */

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}


/* Style page content - use this if you want to push the page content to the right when you open the side navigation */

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 20px;
}

.btmcontainer {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.social li {
  float: right;
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
}

.faqwtb a {
  color: black;
  padding-top: 50rem;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
  <link href="HomeCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="font.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="mediatype and|not|only (expressions)" href="print.css" />
  <script src="GTech.js"></script>
</head>

<div id="page">

  <body>
    <header>
      <img class="logo" src="Images/17622275_1491915637509717_1227569229_o.png" width="250" height="250" />
      <div class="mainnav">
        <button style="height:20px;width:120px;margin-left:90px">Notice</button>
        <button class="divider" style="height:20px;width:120px">Products</button>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button id="svc" style="height:20px;width:120px">Services</button>
          <div id="submenu">
            <a href="#" style="font-family:'Bungee'">Help Center</a>
            <hr />
            <a href="#" style="font-family:'Bungee'">Service Center</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="divider2" style="height:20px;width:120px">About&nbsp;Us</button>
      </div>
    </header>

    <div id="cart" class="scart">
      <span onclick="openNav()"><a href="#">Shopping Cart</a></span>
    </div>

    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <a href="#">Clients</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>

  </body>

  <footer>
    <div class="btmcontainer">
      <div class="faqwtb">
        <span><a href="#">FAQ</a></span>
        <span><a href="#">Where to Buy</a></span>
      </div>
      <div class="btmcol">
        <ul class="social">
          <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="Images/footericon/facebook.png" /></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="Images/footericon/twitter.png" /></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="Images/footericon/google+.png" /></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="Images/footericon/tumblr.png" /></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: Which is your footer??

Comment: <footer>
<div class="btmcontainer">
<div class="faqwtb">
<span><a href="#">FAQ</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Where to Buy</a></span>
</div>
<div class="btmcol">
  <ul class="social">
  <li><a href="#"><img src="Images/footericon/facebook.png"/></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="Images/footericon/twitter.png"/></a></li> 
  <li><a href="#"><img src="Images/footericon/google+.png"/></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="Images/footericon/tumblr.png"/></a></li> 
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
</footer>

This

Comment: The edit link is right there on your question. Why are you 1) posting a comment 2) posting an answer, and 3) editing *somebody else's post* instead of your own question?

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake , i am newbie in this community

Answer (score 1):

Change your CSS to this...

- You have used position relative everywhere. Remove them. Get the position of footer in the correct place and then position your page components.

Check my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mpriyam/s8xhr5wv/

CSS Should be...

```
    body {
  background-image: url(Images/Clean-Gray-BackGround-620x465.jpg);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  margin: 0;
}

#page {
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 1200px;
}

header {
  height: 20px;
  margin: 30px 0 0;
}

.mainnav {
  padding-top: 50px;
  width: 1200px;
}

button {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Bungee';
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 16px 16px 40px 0px;
}

.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.divider {
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 260px;
}

.divider2 {
  margin-left: 150px;
}

#submenu {
  display: none;
  background-color: transparen;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 60px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}

#submenu a {
  color: black;
  padding: 0 0 40 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover #submenu {
  display: block;
}

.logo {
  left: 45%;
  margin: -48px 0 0 -98px;
}

#cart a {
  /* Position them relative to the browser window */
  right: -80px;
  /* Position them outside of the screen */
  transition: 0.3s;
  /* Add transition on hover */
  padding: 15px;
  /* 15px padding */
  width: 100px;
  /* Set a specific width */
  text-decoration: none;
  /* Remove underline */
  font-size: 20px;
  /* Increase font size */
  color: black;
  /* White text color */
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 15px 0px 0px 15px;
}

#cart a:hover {
  right: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  /* 100% Full-height */
  width: 0;
  /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Stay on top */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  /* Black*/
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /* Disable horizontal scroll */
  padding-top: 60px;
  /* Place content 60px from the top */
  transition: 0.5s;
  /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidenav */
}


/* The navigation menu links */

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s
}


/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */

.sidenav a:hover,
.offcanvas a:focus {
  color: blanchedalmond;
}


/* Position and style the close button (top right corner) */

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}


/* Style page content - use this if you want to push the page content to the right when you open the side navigation */

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 20px;
}

.btmcontainer {
  max-width: 1200px;
  clear:both;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.social li {
  float: right;
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
}

.faqwtb a {
  color: black;
  padding-top: 50rem;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
}
```

Comment: Still the same and my logo position has changed to the left side instead of between the 4 navigation bar . What is the purpose of putting position:relative btw ?

Comment: Position: realtive positions the elements inside a container relatively to the element before it.

Comment: Did you check the fiddle?

Comment: Can you post an Image file of How would you want it to look finally?